# mysql connector version not showing while creating dsn

Tags: mysql

On this particular machine (Windows 7 32 bit) I am not able to see the Driver Information of the Connector - although the entry is there  (it shows MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver) - but there is no information in the Version Column or the Company Column - which then am assuming that the driver is not properly installed -

I have tried several times to uninstall/install - or install a different version - it is just not helping.

How do I completely remove the previous version of the Connector that is installed or how do I ensure that the Driver is installed properly.

Please note that this driver is running absolutely fine in other Windows 7 machine (both 32 bit and 64 bit) - it is just this machine which is creating a problem.

Other thing that I want to mention here is that - I am able to install the MySQL Server on this machine - the Query Browser is running fine - Application on other machines can access this server - but the same application does not run on this machine - it throws an error "Data Source Name not found or No Default Driver Found" - it is because of the same Connector problem.

Please help!!